# choosing from an integer arraylist

Tags: java, android

Working in Android studio and as part of a bigger app. I will have an ArrayList of Integers and want to send this to a new instance/screen where each integer in the list displays a string description from which the user can pick whatever entry they want. Once they click it, I want the new instance to send back the integer corresponding to the position in the array of their choice so that I can use it for the next operation.

I made this program as a stand-alone just to get this operation down, but it fails to work (ListChooser has stopped working on load)

my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.kenn.listchooser;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.ListActivity;



public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final String TOTAL_COUNT = "total_count";
public ArrayList<Integer> listValues;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listValues= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listValues.add(1);
    listValues.add(2);
    listValues.add(4);
    listValues.add(5);
}

public int randomMe(View view) {
    Intent randomIntent = new Intent(this, Chooser.class);
    randomIntent.putExtra(TOTAL_COUNT,  listValues);
    startActivity(randomIntent);
    int pick=getIntent().getIntExtra (TOTAL_COUNT, 2);
    return pick;
}
public void action(View view) {
    TextView showCountTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewA);
    showCountTextView.setText(Integer.toString(this.randomMe(view)));
}    }
```

my Chooser.java:

```
package com.example.kenn.listchooser;
import ...
public class Chooser extends ListActivity{
private String TOTAL_COUNT = "total_count";
private TextView text;
private ArrayList<Integer> listHere;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chooser);
    List<Integer> def = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listHere=getIntent().getIntegerArrayListExtra(TOTAL_COUNT);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
    // initiate the listadapter
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter <Integer>(this,
            R.layout.row_layout, R.id.listText, listHere);
    // assign the list adapter
    setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}
// when an item of the list is clicked
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
    String selectedItem = (String) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);
    Intent randomIntent = new Intent(this, com.example.kenn.listchooser.MainActivity.class);
    randomIntent.putExtra(TOTAL_COUNT, selectedItem);
}    }
```

my activity main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/random_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:onClick="action"
    android:text="Choose"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Alert Dialog"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my chooser.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainText"
    android:text="My list" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainText"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:background="#aaaaaa" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainText"
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:text="There is no data"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

my row_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ff00ff" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Any logcats-errors or sth?

Comment: sorry, i am unsure what sth stands for could you clarify?

Comment: It’s alright. I meant, if the app crashes, there must be some errors  or any helpful logs which you can find it in Logcat

Comment: 09-11 03:52:23.151 3048-3048/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to start service while in background: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT pkg=com.google.android.apps.messaging cmp=com.google.android.apps.messaging/.fcm.BugleFirebaseInstanceIDService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{6ea733a u0a83 RCVR idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}